# Android service- how to communicate with activities

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I'm wondering which is the best way to communicate between a Service and an activity..

- Broadcast intent
- Callback
- others?...

Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been running into pretty much the same problem. Take a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476005/how-to-establish-a-two-way-communication-between-activity-and-service-in-differen), answers turned out extremely useful for me.
In fact I haven't directly used a service in the end but switched to the AlarmManager. Worked out as I initially wanted it to be. Good luck