# Android Activity and Service communication: how to keep the UI up-to-date

Tags: android-activity, android-service, android, android-handler

I have an **Activity A** (not the main Activity) that launches a **Service S** that does some stuff in the background and, in the meanwhile, should made some changes to the UI of A.

Let's just say that **S count from 0 to 100** and **A should display this count in Real-Time**. Since the real job of S is quite more complicated and CPU-consuming, I do not want to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for it (indeed *"AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) [...]"*) but just a regular [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) started in a new Thread (an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) would be fine as well).

This is my **Activity A**:

```
public class A extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Activity";
    private TextView countTextView;    // TextView that shows the number
    Button startButton;                // Button to start the count
    BResultReceiver resultReceiver;


    /**
     * Receive the result from the Service B.
     */
    class BResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
        public BResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            switch ( resultCode )  {
                case B.RESULT_CODE_COUNT:
                        String curCount = resultData.getString(B.RESULT_KEY_COUNT);
                        Log.d(TAG, "ResultReceived: " + curCount + "\n");
                        runOnUiThread( new UpdateUI(curCount) );  // NOT WORKING AFTER onResume()!!!
                   break;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Runnable class to update the UI.
     */
    class UpdateUI implements Runnable {
        String updateString;

        public UpdateUI(String updateString) {
            this.updateString = updateString;
        }

        public void run() {
            countTextView.setText(updateString);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.counter);

        countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countTextView);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        resultReceiver = new BResultReceiver(null);
    }


    public void startCounting(View view) {
        startButton.setEnabled(false);

        //Start the B Service:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
        intent.putExtra("receiver", resultReceiver);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

And this is my **Service B**:

```
public class B extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "Service";
    private Looper serviceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler serviceHandler;
    private ResultReceiver resultReceiver;
    private Integer count;

    static final int RESULT_CODE_COUNT = 100;
    static final String RESULT_KEY_COUNT = "Count";


    /**
     * Handler that receives messages from the thread.
     */
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            while ( count < 100 ) {
                count++;
                //Sleep...
                sendMessageToActivity(RESULT_CODE_COUNT, RESULT_KEY_COUNT, count.toString());
            }

            //Stop the service (using the startId to avoid stopping the service in the middle of handling another job...):
            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //Start up the thread running the service:
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

        this.count = 0;

        //Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        serviceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(serviceLooper);
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        this.resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");

        //For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job:
        Message msg = serviceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        serviceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        //If we get killed, after returning from here, restart:
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Send a message from to the activity.
     */
    protected void sendMessageToActivity(Integer code, String name, String text) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(name, text);

        //Send the message:
        resultReceiver.send(code, bundle);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but **if I click the *back button* (or the *home button*) and then I re-open the Activity A then the UI of A is not updated anymore** (it just shows the initial configuration of A - i.e. the "startButton" is still clickable and the count is not showed - it seems *runOnUiThread(...)* is not working anymore). However, **the Service B is still running in the background** and the I can see the correct count is passed to the Activity A in the *Log.d(...)*. Finally, if I click on the "startButton" again, the counting does not start from the beginning (0) but from where B has been arrived (I've double checked it by showing it in the notification bar).

How can I fix this behaviour? I would like that, when I re-open the Activity A, it automatically continues to receive and update the data from the Service B. Or, in other words, that the Service keeps the UI of the Activity A up-to-date.

Please give me some hints, links or piece of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you click back button your `Activity` is destroyed. When you start the `Activity` again you get a new `Activity`. That also happen when you rotate the device. This is [Android lifecycle event](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

The Activity is not good for heavy Business Logic only to show stuff/control stuf.
What you have to do is create a simple MVC, [Model View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android). The view (`Activity`) should only be used for showing results and controlling the eventflow.

The `Service` can hold an Array of the `count` and when your `Activity` start it will `onBind()` your Service that is running (or if not running will start the `Service` since you bind to it) Let the Activity(View) get the Array of results and show it. This simple setup exclude the (M)Model Business Logic.

**Update**
Following up a bit read this it's Android official docs and perfect start since it do kind of what you asking. As you see in the example in the `onStart()` the Activity establish a connection with the service and in the `onStop()` the connection is removed. There's no point having a connection after on `onStop()`. Just like you asking for. I would go with this setup and not let the `Service` continuously sending data because that would drain resources and the `Activity` is not always listening because it will stop when in the background.
[Here's an activity that binds to LocalService and calls getRandomNumber() when a button is clicked:](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! OK for the MVC model but, from a performance point of view, won't be better if the Service sends automatically data to the Activity, rather then having an Activity that continuously asks for them? Isn't there a way to re-connect the "new Activity" and the "old Service" in the Activity onResume()/onStart() methods?

Comment: Yes it can be done in both ways it all depends on what works for you. It´s best you read about it to get a clear picture, quite straight forward in the Android docs. I updated my answer..

Comment: I'm messing up it a bit, but still no luck! I don't understand why I can see the right number in the Log.d(...) inside Activity A even after the onRestart() event, but the TextView does not update until I click the Button again... might the problem be that I don't bind the Service B to the Activity A?

Comment: Looks like a `NullPointerException` in the `Service` when you do this `count++;`. Add some `android.util.Log.e(TAG, "shit errror")`. Maybe your using LogCat already, unless it show the `NullPointerException`

Comment: Of course, this wasn't the problem in question. No idea why, when I edited the code before, I've deleted the initializaton (this.count = 0) in the onCreate() method. Anyway, my problem is still there. I've found this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476005/how-to-establish-a-two-way-communication-between-activity-and-service-in-differe

Comment: Place a `Log.e(TAG...` in all methods and trace what happens. Also debug stepping, I guess your already doing this but anyway

Comment: I've finally manage it working using a LocalBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Yea `BroadcastReceiver` is good sending `Intent` the Android way. I tested your code in your question and it's working. Maybe you forgot to add your `B` `service` to `AndroidManifest` as `<service android:name="com.example.test.B"/>`